# How to change arrow icon once click dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
 <div class="selectContainer">
            <ul>
                <li class="init">Select</li>
                <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
                <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>                                                          
            </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .selectcontainer ul li
  {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
 .selectcontainer ul li:not(.init){
    display:none;
    float:left;
  }
 li.init{cursor:pointer; background:url("../images/arrow-down.png") right no-repeat;}
 li.init1 { cursor: pointer; background:url("../images/arrow-up.png") right no-repeat;}
```

JQuery:

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $( "ul" ).click(function() {
        $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').slideToggle(200);
        });

        $( "li" ).click(function() {
        $("li .init").addClass("li .init1");
        });
   });
```

Hi I just have to change my image when dropdown is open up arrow and when close down arrow.
This code is not working please help.

Comment: Change `$("li .init").addClass("li .init1");` to `$("li.init").removeClass("init").addClass("init1");`

Comment: Do you want to show the arrow per each option? if not why are you adding `init` to `<li>` instead of `<ul>`..? are you trying to make nested drop downs..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

You were not toggling "init1" class (first `<li>`) on click of `<ul>`, so your arrows were not changing on click.

```
$("ul").click(function () {
    $(this).children('li:not(.init)').slideToggle(200);
    $(this).find("li.init").toggleClass("init1");
});
```

Below is the JS fiddle working example, i have used special characters and :after pseudo class for up/down arrows , you can change as it suits you.

http://jsfiddle.net/4C5ND/

Answer (score 0):

SO simple .U could use `transform:rotate(180deg);` CSS on click.

Comment: I have to put that as image. so in "li" have to put addClass and give image for that...?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if($(this).hasClass("class1")){
 $(this).removeClass("class1").addClass("class2");
}else{
 $(this).removeClass("class2").addClass("class1");
}
```